# Converting 5V from Raspberry Pi to 3.3V at MCP23017

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am trying to utilise a Raspberry Pi's 5V output to push more current towards sensors connected to an MCP23017 i2c port expander. However, the MCP23017 requires that I down-convert the voltage to 3.3V.

To do convert from the Raspberry Pi's 5V supply to 3.3V, I'm using an LD1117V33 voltage regulator, a 100nF 16V ceramic capacitor, and a 10uF 16V electrolytic capacitor connected as shown in the diagram below.

[image: 5V to 3.3V conversion diagram]

- Pi's 5V output goes into the left pin of the LD1117V33, which connects to the  the + (left) pin of the electrolytic capacitor.
- The middle pin of the LD1117v33 connects to the - (right) pin of the electrolytic capacitor, the left pin of the ceramic capacitor, and through to the ground.
- The right pin of the LD1117V33 connects to the right pin of the ceramic capacitor. It is supposed to output a 3.3V supply for the MCP23017 (but it does not).
- MCP23017 output connects to the ground.
- The ground in this diagram connects to the Pi's ground.

The MCP23017 works normally when connected to the Pi's 3.3V output. **Why doesn't it work with the power regulator, shown above, connected to the Pi's 5V output?**

Comment: Do you have a multimeter? You should measure voltages. Also, just be sure to double-check the pins against the datasheet.

Comment: voltages, eh. i should do that. yeah, datasheet pins is proabbly it, i tried different pins and it got really hot so i got worried. thanks, mate.

Comment: Why are you hooking it up without checking the datasheet? That's a pretty surefire way to ruin components.

Comment: thanks. im follwoing a step by step tutorial without having full knowledge of what im doing.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the datasheet, you have the pins wrong. [image]

Pin 1 should be Ground, Pin 2 should go to your sensors, pin 3 should go to the 5V from the Raspbery Pi.

Comment: so its probably hte pins, same as the other comment. oops, probably should have checked datasheet. thank you.

Comment: NEVER use a part you haven't used before without checking the datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so initially i was too scared to try to troubleshoot because i was wroking on a tutorial andi was worried i was going to fry my pi, but i checked the datasheet and wired it up accordingly and checked the voltages wtihy m multimetre and im getting 3.5v which is pretty close, so thanks everyone.